# Ionic Cards not displaying if using <ion-card>

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

Hi I want to use ionic cards in my app , but if i am using `<ion-card>` , like

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    This is a Card
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

it is just displayed as plaint text , but if i use something like this

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    This is a Card
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine.

Please help!

Comment: Are you using Ionic 1 or 2? Ion-card is only available in Ionic 2 as far as I know.

Comment: my bad , i just found out , Yes you are right @henmer

Comment: @henmer , one question , if that is the case why <ion-tabs> is working for me ?

Comment: It is just a matter of which directives that are included in Ionic 1. Ionic 2 added some new ones. Make sure you use the documentation for Ionic 1 when developing your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ion-card is only available in Ionic 2